# Can a closed rectifiable curve be "bad" in all directions?

Tags: gn.general-topology

How can one tell whether a point $P$ not on a closed rectifiable curve $C$ is inside or outside $C$?

If $C$ is piecewise smooth one can throw a ray $R$ from $P$ in a random direction and count the number of intersections between $C$ and $R$. Odd - $P$ is in; even - $P$ is out. If the a line segment of $C$ lies on $R$ one can either collapse it into a single point.

Now, if $C$ is merely rectifiable then it's not clear that the number of intersections between $C$ and $R$ is going to be finite. Thus the questions:

Is it possible for a rectifiable curve $C$ and a point $P$ be in such position that for *a* ray $R$ the number of intersections between $C$ and $R$ will be infinite (apart of line segments of $C$ lying on $R$)?

Is it possible for the above travesty to happen for *every* ray $R$ from a fixed point $P$?

Comment: I take it that your curve $C$ is a Jordan curve? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JordanCurve.html

Comment: Not for a rectifiable curve and all directions (the average number of intersections is bounded by the length divided by the distance from $P$ to $C$ with a factor $2\pi$ somewhere). As to a single direction, the intersection may be any compact set you want.

Comment: @fedja is that also the case for rectifyable fractal curves, resp., do all fractal Jordan curves have infinite length?

Comment: @fedja : Perhaps you can post a more detailed version of your comment as an answer. When I tried to flesh it out for myself, I got confused about how to treat line segments lying on the ray.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I'm curious for both. For non-Jordan one should slightly modify the above algorithm, counting signed crossings between $R$ and $C$ rather than their parity, but the rest of the question will stand.

Comment: What prevents you to make a Jordan curve from a spiral, like $x=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}\cos\frac{1}{t}$, $y=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}\sin\frac{1}{t}$, $0<t\le 1$? Then each ray that intersects zero will have infinite number of intersections with this curve.

Comment: @TimothyChow. Slight elaboration of Fedja's argument .If you consider the central projection from C to the circle with center P and radius distance from P to C and apply the simplest version of Eilenberg's inequality ( Coarea inequality) you will get that the result. See for example Federer Geometric Measure theory corollary 2.10.11page 176 for necessary coarea inequality.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, Jordan curve is supposed to be closed.

Comment: Michael, you can rotate it to, say, the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ around the point $(0,0)$, and you'll get a domain, which boundary will be two curves like this and a part of the unit circle, and this will be a Jordan curve.

Comment: Pardon, the circle will be not unit, it will have the radius $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, $lim_{t\to 0}$ would be $(0,0)$, combine with the compactness of the Jordan curve and you get $(0,0)$ lying on the curve, which disqualifies it from the question. More generally, I don't think that the approach "produce a spiral that rotates around $P$ infinitely many times" would produce a Jordan curve counterexample: the rings of the spiral would have to accumulate somewhere.

Comment: Michael, I think, you did not understand. We can extend $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ to the closed interval $[0,1]$ by putting $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=0$. Then $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ will be a smooth map from $[0,1]$ into ${\mathbb R}^2$. And if we do what I said with this curve (i.e. add the same curve rotated to some angle around zero and an arc of a corresponding circle), we'll get a Jordan curve. And it will be rectifiable since the derivatives $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ are also continuous(/smooth) maps defined on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

A candidate curve  with few directions with finite number of intersections might constructed from the [Blancmange curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) as a fractal curve, that can serve as a building block for constructing "evil" Jordan curves with Hausdorff dimension 1 (for the properties of the more general Takagi functions refer to e.g. [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4205.pdf)).

The simplest idea would be to take the union of the curve itself and its reflection at the x-axis (refering to the images on the linked webseite).

A bit more complicated is the idea of constructing an analoge of a "sine wave" by point-reflecting the curve at one of its endpoints and use a phase shifted version of the result as an analogue of a "cosine wave". A parametric function $x(t)=cosinewave(t),\ y(t)=sinewave(t)$ may be even better, but I haven't done any investigations on whether the set of inner point of the region bounded by that "*Blancmonge circle*" is connected.

**Caveat:**
But, despite having Hausdorff dimension 1, the resulting curves are not rectifiable and thus *not* an example of the sought kind of curves.